# What does the phrase "just a bagel" mean in Chicago (the musical)?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the 1975 musical *Chicago*, the song *Razzle Dazzle* has the following lines:

> Throw 'em a fake and a finagle
>
> They'll never know you're just a bagel

What does it mean to be "just a bagel" in this case? In context, it seems like something negative and/or insignificant. However, I can't find any other instances of "bagel" being used this way.

I've searched google for "just a bagel" in quotes, but most are references to the food. There are also a few references to "bagel" as slang, such as [this site](https://forward.com/culture/185344/bageling-means-many-things-not-all-of-them-fit-f/) or the [tennis term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagel_(tennis)), but none of them seem to fit the context of the musical itself.

An ideal answer would have some basis in American English during the 1920's, which is the era in which the play is set, or during the 1970's, which is when the play was written. Of course, I'd be willing to accept any valid answer too.

Comment: Just a ring of dough (skin) with a big empty hole in the centre (no heart/soul/brain), perhaps? Good question (though I’d suggest editing the question to add in where specifically you’ve looked in vain for similar uses).

Comment: Not knowing the musical, only very very vaguely, who is the person being called  "bagel"? Is it a woman, a man, someone Jewish, someone from New York? Someone who is very plain and insipid? I mean [bagels](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/recipe/bagel-recipe/) are just soft rolls of bread... hardly exciting stuff.

Comment: [UrbanDictionary’s definition #5](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bagel&defid=1147368) doesn’t seem like it’s relevant either…

Comment: Note the similarity to expressions like "plain vanilla" or "white bread" -- basically unremarkable stuff.

Comment: @Mari-LouA '_Just_ rolls of bread'? How dare you.

Comment: Ya know, these are just lyrics. Just getting bagel and finagle to fit in to rhyme is pretty clever. To have it actually mean anything is asking a lot.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the musical is set in 1920's Chicago (and was written in the 70s). The context is that a lawyer is telling his client, a white woman (I don't think she's specified as Jewish), to "razzle dazzle" the judge and jury.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, I agree with that, and I'd be fine if this question ends up being unanswerable in general. Still, this line has been bothering me and it'd be nice to have closure of some kind, even if the answer is just "nobody can know".

Comment: I have no reason to  believe it's a reference to anything other than the toroidal bread.  The bread is well-known, especially in cities, and is rather mundane -- the sort of thing that makes a fine metaphor.

Comment: I wonder if the lyricist was conflating "bagel" and "bagatelle"? I remember thinking they were connected in some way when I first heard *bagatelle*, especially after learning that the French word for "ring" was "bague". I think my muddled reasoning was something along the lines of *rings are small, and shaped like a zero; a "bagatelle" could be a "little bague", so particularly trifling; and maybe "bagel" comes from "bague" since it's shaped like a ring*.

Comment: @1006a: the Chicago lyricist, [Fred Ebb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Ebb), was Jewish, and grew up in New York City. I think he knew the difference between a bagel and a bagatelle.

Comment: @PeterShor It's just a wild theory,not an answer, but there doesn't seem to be much evidence for any other theory. I'm sure he knew what a bagel was (I certainly knew what a bagel was long before I learned the word bagatelle, let alone *bague*), but that doesn't mean that he didn't somehow equate the terms—or at least hope his audience would—when reaching for a rhyme that meant something like "loser".

Answer (score 2):

The word "doughnut" is occasionally used to mean "zero"; see this [article](https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/media-centre/blog/2015/12/bankers-told-to-expect-doughnut-bonuses/) for an example.

Obviously, this meaning originated in the similarity of shape.

A bagel, like a doughnut, has a hole in it, so I expect the songwriters intended the meaning to be the same. I also expect they thought this meaning would be clearer than it actually seems to be.

Comment: If the reference were to the bagel as a symbol for zero then some phrasing such as "a big fat bagel" would have been used to prod forward that implication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the lyricist may know otherwise but it appears to be a rhyme and a juxtaposition: **a common or ordinary** person, who razzles and dazzles and convinces the audience he is a star! See this google book link:  [google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=MuKxAAAAIAAJ&q=%22you%27re%20just%20a%20bagel%22&dq=%22you%27re%20just%20a%20bagel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx1cK4_qbbAhXQ3FMKHZ_JB9IQ6AEIMzAC)

More on the **bagel** the the **ordinary**:  [article](https://forward.com/food/396688/how-the-non-jewish-begyl-became-the-jewish-bagel/)

> So as Yiddish declined, the **bagel** rose. In this round piece of
>   boiled-and-baked dough, lies the story of how **ordinary people**
>   fought to retain a grasp on their identity.

and  [TimesofIsrael](https://www.timesofisrael.com/the-bagel-and-falafel-an-edible-jewish-identity/)

The bagel ... ended up epitomizing the modern Jewish ... the complex and often contradictory ways in which **'ordinary' people** tried ...

The full lyrics here: [genius.com](https://genius.com/Richard-gere-razzle-dazzle-lyrics)

Comment: I'll add that you can "dress up" a bagel with various spreads, slices of cheese and meat, etc, but, under it all, it's still a (reasonably good but not remarkable) plain old bagel.

Comment: Please support your affirmation that a bagel refers to a common or an ordinary person. Can you find other instances where the metaphorical meaning is repeated?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  i shall continue my research.  You are welcome to help me ... lol.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  i believe i have found 2 more affirmations.  What do you think?

Comment: They're close..., but you found instances where the words ordinary and bagel were juxtaposed, not where "bagel" was used figuratively.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks ... i will use juxtaposition ... best my ordinary brain can do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You yourself made that claim in a comment an hour before lbf posted his answer -- "bagels are just soft rolls of bread... hardly exciting stuff."

Comment: @HotLicks but it was me guessing, I'm not American, and I didn't know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Uh, a bagel isn't "American".  If anything, it's Polish.

Comment: @HotLicks The musical is called Chicago, and the lyrics are not in Polish.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Chicago is, and was, a very cosmopolitan city.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  i support your guess! cc hotlicks